# how can I convert Google sheets values (lat and long, two columns) to double for mapping?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a google sheet containing an unknown number of lat and long points along with a name identifier.
I can get names lat and long to print. However, I cant' seem to get them to plot because I need a "double" type, and all I can get is a map string string type. Is there any way to make this work?

Code:

```
    Iterable markers = [];

    var latstr = (sheet.values.map.column(3)); toString(); //latitude
    var lngstr = (sheet.values.map.column(4)); toString(); //longitude

    List<dynamic> names = [];
    List<double> lat = [];
    List<double> lng = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      
      names.add(await sheet.values.map.column(2));
      lat.add(await (sheet.values.map.column(3)));
      lng.add(await sheet.values.map.column(4));
    }

      setState(() async {

        _markers.addAll([
          Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId("[0]"),
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'test 1' + " " + "test"),
              position: LatLng(lat, lng)),
        ]
        );
      });
  }
```

I also don't know if the markers.addAll function will work at all. Probably not. I could really use some help with that as well, please.

Comment: just convert ->  Double long = Double.parseDouble(string_value) ?;

Comment: like this? latstr = Double.parseDouble(sheet.values.map.column(2));

The method parseDouble isn't defined for type 'Double'

Comment: you want to use the lowercase version of double. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/parse.html

Comment: didn't work. It won't even detect double parse as a valid entry.